# Custom Variable Types Lua

Tags: variables, lua

I am looking for a library/function in lua that allows you to have custom variable types (even be detected as your custom type using the "type" method). I'm trying to make a json encoder/decoder that has the custom type "json." I want a solution that can be done in lua alone.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot create new Lua types, but you can mimick their creation to a good extent using metatables and tables. For example:

```
local frobnicator_metatable = {}
frobnicator_metatable.__index = frobnicator_metatable

function frobnicator_metatable.ToString( self )
    return "Frobnicator object\n"
        .. "  field1 = " .. tostring( self.field1 ) .. "\n"
        .. "  field2 = " .. tostring( self.field2 )
end


local function NewFrobnicator( arg1, arg2 )
    local obj = { field1 = arg1, field2 = arg2 }
    return setmetatable( obj, frobnicator_metatable )
end

local original_type = type  -- saves `type` function
-- monkey patch type function
type = function( obj )
    local otype = original_type( obj )
    if  otype == "table" and getmetatable( obj ) == frobnicator_metatable then
        return "frobnicator"
    end
    return otype
end

local x = NewFrobnicator()
local y = NewFrobnicator( 1, "hello" )

print( x )
print( y )
print( "----" )
print( "The type of x is: " .. type(x) )
print( "The type of y is: " .. type(y) )
print( "----" )
print( x:ToString() )
print( y:ToString() )
print( "----" )
print( type( "hello!" ) )  -- just to see it works as usual
print( type( {} ) )  -- just to see it works as usual
```

**Output:**

```
table: 004649D0
table: 004649F8
----
The type of x is: frobnicator
The type of y is: frobnicator
----
Frobnicator object
  field1 = nil
  field2 = nil
Frobnicator object
  field1 = 1
  field2 = hello
----
string
table
```

Of course the example is simplistic and there are more things to say about object oriented programming in Lua. You may find the following references useful:

- [Lua WIKI OOP index page](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientedProgramming).
- [Lua WIKI page: Object Orientation Tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientationTutorial).
- [Chapter on OOP of Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html). It is the first book edition, so it is focused on Lua 5.0, but the core material still applies.

Comment: For your type() function here, what I usually do is implement a __type field in the metatable which describes the classname. Then type will always be a useful value for all classes.

Comment: @Zeksie Yep, that's definitely an option. As I said, there is really much more to say about OOP in Lua.

Comment: Could you make a function that would make a custom variable type? For example: `jsonCode = {"json text here"} varType(jsonCode, "json")` would return simply `jsonCode` with the custom type `"json"`. `tostring(jsonCode)` would just return `jsonCode[1]` (which would, in this case, be equal to `"json text here"`). Don't bother to implement the 2-value system you have here, I will only be using it with table that have 1 value.

Answer (score 5):

What you are asking for is not possible, not even with the C API. There simply are only the builtin types in Lua, there is no way of adding more. However, using metamethods and tables you can craft (functions creating) tables that come *very* close to custom types/classes in other languages. See for example [Programming in Lua: Object-Oriented Programming](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html) (but keep in mind that the book was written for Lua 5.0, so some details might have changed).